# knockout.js and view models with existing getters/setters (not ko.observable)

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

knockout.js seems to be optimized for object/field binding and can use [ko.observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) to create getter/setter functions.

But what if the members of the view models I want to bind to already are getter/setter functions?  What is the simplest way to get these two integrated?

```
var example = {
    FirstName: function(/* setValue */) { ... };
    LastName: function(/* setValue */) { ... };
    ArrayOfSomething: function(index /*, setValue */) { ... };
}
```

Do I have to create a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) (which seems complicated) or is there another mechanism?

How will this work for `ArrayOfSomething`?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to make them `ko.observable`?

Comment: The view models are from a different library - I don't have control over that, basically.

Comment: I would recommend making your own viewModel (with KO) to wrap them then. It will save you many headaches.

Comment: but that defeats the benefits of binding

Comment: No it doesn't. The benefits of binding are 1) ensuring that data represented on the UI (especially in MULTIPLE PLACES) remains consistent with the underlying model 2) ensuring that dependent changes cascade automatically, and 3) ensuring that all your data is in a coherent model (single location). A KO viewmodel still has all of these benefits, with the added benefit of being in YOUR CONTROL, an invaluable benefit for someone developing software. In fact, MVVM generally recommends you make your own viewModel to wrap domain models. This is no different.

Comment: I appreciate your attention to the issue, but your comments boil down to "Why would you want to do *that*?!?"  I have objects dedicated to be be view models and they serve only this purpose, yet they must operate this way.

Comment: No, you have objects dedicated to be models. To be viewmodels, they have to work between the model and the view. In knockout, that means they need to be observables. If Knockout could work without observables, I think they would have done that already. My comment isn't *why* would you want to do that, my comment is "you are doing it *wrong*."

Comment: So if you had to bind to setter/getter-member-function-having objects, how would you most easily bind a KO model to them?  Custom bindings?  Writable computed observables?  Is there a way to encapsulate the problem?

Comment: The problem is the notification of change to subscribers. You would have to modify the setters to publish the change, or poll them for changes. Polling has the problem of disposal tracking, and just generally poor performance. Which of those sounds better?